# Approximation of Sum of Squares of Sine

Tags: trigonometry, approximation

Given the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^x \sin^2(\frac{33}{n})$$ is there an approximation for this sum? Preferably, it gets closer to the actual sum as $x$ grows larger (like the approximation for the harmonic numbers).

If it helps anyone, these is a closed form for $$\sum_{n=1}^x \sin^2(n)= \frac{1}{4} (2 x - \csc(1) \sin(2 x + 1) + 1)$$

Comment: $ n  $ should go from 1 otherwise the series won't be defined for $ n = 0 $

Comment: @DinnoKoluh Thank you! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let us transform square of sine using $\sin^2 t=(1-\cos 2t)/2$ and using the Taylor expansion of cosine:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^x\sin^2\left(\frac{33}n\right)&=
\frac x2-\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^x\cos\left(\frac{66}n\right)
=\frac x2-\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\cdot\left(\frac{66}n\right)^{2k}\\
&=\frac x2-\frac 12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-4356)^k}{(2k)!}\cdot H_x^{(2k)}
\end{align*}
where $H_x^{(2k)}$ is the generalized harmonic number.

---

I have got the following additional idea:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^x\sin^2\left(\frac{33}n\right)
&=\frac x2-\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^x\cos\left(\frac{66}n\right)
=\frac x2-\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^x\Re\left(\cos\frac 1n+\mathrm i\cdot\sin\frac 1n\right)^{66}\\[12pt]
&=\frac x2-\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^x\Re\left(\sum_{k=0}^{66}\binom{66}{k}\cos^k\frac 1n\cdot\mathrm i^{66-k}\cdot\sin^{66-k}\frac 1n\right)\\[12pt]
&=\frac x2-\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^x\Re\left(\sum_{k=0}^{66}\binom{66}{k}\cos^k\frac 1n\cdot\mathrm i^{66-k}\cdot\sin^{66-k}\frac 1n\right)\\[12pt]
&=\frac x2-\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^x\sum_{\substack{k=0\\\text{$k$ is even}}}^{66}\binom{66}{k}(-1)^{\frac k2+1}\cos^k\frac 1n\cdot\sin^{66-k}\frac 1n\\[12pt]
&=\frac x2-\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^x\sum_{j=0}^{33}\binom{66}{2j}(-1)^{j+1}\cos^{2j}\frac 1n\cdot\sin^{66-2j}\frac 1n\\[12pt]
&\approx\frac x2-\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^x\sum_{j=0}^{33}\binom{66}{2j}(-1)^{j+1}\left(1-\frac 1{2!\cdot n^2}+\frac 1{4!\cdot n^4}-\frac 1{6!\cdot n^6}\right)^{2j}\\[12pt]
&\quad\cdot\left(\frac 1n-\frac 1{3!\cdot n^3}+\frac 1{5!\cdot n^5}-\frac 1{7!\cdot n^7}\right)^{66-2j}
\end{align*}

The more terms of Taylor series of sine and cosine function are used the better approximation you get.

Comment: Interestingly enough, $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-4356)^k}{(2k)!}$$ is almost equal to $-\frac 12$

Comment: How do I approximate $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\frac{(-4356)^k}{(2k)!}\cdot H_x^{(2k)})$?

Comment: Instead of infinite sum you can consider the finite sum. Harmonic number can be approximated by the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Also, I tried graphing it, but doesn't work. As in, doesn't equal my original equation.

Comment: The first summand, $\cos(66)$, can be approximated by the Taylor series of $\cos(x)$ at the center $x_0=0$ worse than $\cos(t)$ with $t$ is close to 0. Therefore you have take the first 100 terms of infinite series to get good approximation (thanks to Mathematica v. 11.2). $$\sum_{n=1}^x\sin^2\left(\frac{33}n\right)\approx\frac x2-\frac 12\sum_{k=0}^{100}\frac{(-4356)^k}{(2k)!}\cdot H_x^{(2k)}$$ Euler's transformation of the alternating series accelerate its convergence and may give the better approximation.

Comment: Most calculators can't handle $200!$ Also, How good would the approximation be? Also, even with that, it won't work.